# How to check whether rectangle is golden rectangle using Fibonacci and recursion function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I tried to write a c++ program to check wether is a golden rectangle or not by using Fibonacci series (if Fibonacci term = length the previous Fibonacci series should = the breadth ) that is mean it's a golden rectangle else not golden rectangle ..
I get error stack overflow ..!!!

This my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int fib (int);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    int length;
    cout << "enter the Length " << endl;
    cin>> length ;
    int breadth;
    cout << "enter the Breadth " << endl;
    cin>> breadth ;
    int x ;
    cout << "enter the limit " << endl;
    cin>> x ;
    cout << endl ;
    for (int i =1 ; i <= x ; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Fibonacci"<<"=" <<fib(i) <<" "<<"Counter =" <<  (i) << endl;
        if ((breadth == (fib(i)-1)) && ( length == fib(i)))
        {
            cout << " rectangle";
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "This is not rectangle";
        }
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
int fib (int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    if (n == 2)
        return 2;
    return fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2);
}
```

Comment: Find another way instead of recursion.

Comment: What were your inputs? A too huge value for `x` may produce a ... stack overflow!

Comment: I just wanted to point out that, if a rectangle measuring 3x5 is a golden rectangle, then a rectangle measuring 6x10 is also golden. Whether a rectangle is golden does not depend on the units of measurement, but on _the ratio of length to width_, which by definition is dimensionless.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your comments, my logic is if the fibonacci series generates 1 2 3 5 8 13......

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your comments, my logic is if the fibonacci series generates 1 2 3 5 8 13...... Based on the next fib no equal the current no + previous no.. Or return fib(n-1) + fib(n+2).. If current no  in fib series  length of golden rectangle the previous no should be the breadth of golden rectangle.. I want to approve that through fibonacci and recursion fib function..

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
return fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2);
```

for recursively computing the Fibonacci sequence is not the right strategy. It leads to a lot of unnecessary duplicate computations and recursive calls.

It is preferable to use an iterative approach.

```
int fib (int n)
{
   int s1 = 0;
   int s2 = 1;
   for ( int iter = 1; iter <= n; ++iter )
   {
      int temp = s1;
      s1 = s2;
      s2 = temp + s1;
   }

   return s2;
}
```

If you must use a recursive approach, you need a helper function that makes the recursion less onerous.

```
int fib_helper(int s1, int s2, int iter, int n)
{
   if ( iter == n )
   {
      return s2;
   }
   return fib_helper(s2, s1+s2, iter+1, n);
}

int fib (int n)
{
   return fib_helper(0, 1, 1, n);
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your comments, my logic is if the fibonacci series generates 1 2 3 5 8 13...... Based on the next fib no equal the current no + previous no.. Or return fib(n-1) + fib(n+2).. If current no in fib series length of golden rectangle the previous no should be the breadth of golden rectangle.. I want to approve that through fibonacci and recursion fib function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything in one go. There is no need to calculate Fibonacci numbers multiple times:

```
int lastFib = 1;
int currentFib = 1;
while(length >= currentFib)
{
    //Check if the current pair of Fibonacci numbers matches the rectangle
    if(length == currentFib && width == lastFib)
    {
        std::cout << "This is a golden rectangle" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    //Calculate the next Fibonacci number
    int nextFib = lastFib + currentFib;
    lastFib = currentFib;
    currentFib = nextFib;
}
//We left the loop without returning, i.e., the rectangle is not golden.
std::cout << "This is not a golden rectangle" << std::endl;
```

Comment: 1,1,2,3,5.... so a rectangle that's 3x5 is a golden ratio rectangle. But so is a 6x10...

Comment: @Tim: I don't understand your comment. 6x10 is not a golden rectangle per the OP's definition.

Comment: I'm just trying to point out something that the OP seems to have overlooked. I'll add a comment to the original question.

Comment: @Tim I see your point, but I think the definition is as intended. After all, we are dealing with integers and we essentially allow a larger tolerance for the ratio of small integers than of larger ones (as you move towards larger FIbonacci numbers, the ratio gets closer and closer to the actual golden ratio). So strictly speaking, neither 3x5 nor 6x10 is a golden rectangle. But on its scale, 3x5 is vaguely ok, whereas 6x10 is too far off (5x8 would be better on that scale).

Comment: on reflection, I think you're right. We should just see this as a computer science problem and not a question of mathematics